# Ceph cannot reformat because disk is mounted

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ceph

I am using MaaS 1.8, trying to use the juju-deployer with

```
juju-deployer -c config.yaml -d vivid-kilo -e envName
```

Here is my config.
http://pastebin.com/TsvdnSKA

Here is the error output:
http://pastebin.com/PmXF8rN7

Here is the ceph error:
http://pastebin.com/8fsu1hLx

It is saying that it can't reformat a drive because it is already mounted.

Any help is appreciated